# TypeConverter function never used room database

Tags: android, android-studio, android-room

I have list of custom object that i wanna save it in the database.

So I have to use TypeConverters to make this possible.

My problem that i get an error when I implement the functionality and I noticed

that a function annotated with TypeConverter never used

Here's the error:

```
A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptExecution
error: The columns returned by the query does not have the fields [avatar,email,first_name,id,last_name] in com.hraa.fakeusers.model.UserData even though they are annotated as non-null or primitive. Columns returned by the query: [data]
    public abstract androidx.lifecycle.LiveData<java.util.List<com.hraa.fakeusers.model.UserData>> getUsers();
```

And here's the code:

```
@Entity(tableName = USER_DATA_TABLE)
data class DataModel(
    val data: List<UserData>,
    val page: Int,
    val per_page: Int,
    val total: Int,
    val total_pages: Int
) {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    var id: Int? = null
}

data class UserData(
    val avatar: String,
    val email: String,
    val first_name: String,
    val id: Int,
    val last_name: String
)

class Converters {

    @TypeConverter
    fun toUsersData(value: String): List<UserData> {
        val type = object : TypeToken<List<UserData>>() {}.type
        return Gson().fromJson(value, type)
    }

    @TypeConverter
    fun fromUsersData(usersData: List<UserData>): String {
        return Gson().toJson(usersData)
    }
}

@Database(entities = [DataModel::class], version = 1, exportSchema = false)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class AppDatabase: RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun dataDao(): DataDao
}

    @Dao
interface DataDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun insertData(data: DataModel)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteData(data: DataModel)

    @Query("SELECT data FROM USER_DATA_TABLE")
    fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<UserData>>
}
```

Note: toUsersData() function never used.. I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: toUsersData() function never used

How can you be sure of that? My guess is that this function could work well, but you have two type's transformations here:

```
@Query("SELECT data FROM USER_DATA_TABLE")
fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<UserData>>
```

**Transformation #1 (row level).** Input: String (saved in db). Output: data (List).
That should be processed well thanks to your toUsersData() method (may be not, I've not checked, but it seems it should do)

**Transformation #2 (row level).** Input: data (List). Output: UserData (According to your desired return type). For that Room doesn't know how to do this transformation, so you have en error.

To check if your `toUsersData()` really works you can test next query:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM USER_DATA_TABLE")
fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<DataModel>>
```

If your build is successful, then there is no problem with this function. You can also find this function in Java-class, that was autogenerated by Room during build.

You can try to add another data class:

```
data class UserDataList(
    val data: List<UserData>
)
```

and change your data method to:

```
@Query("SELECT data FROM USER_DATA_TABLE")
fun getUsers(): LiveData<List<UserDataList>>
```

Comment: About toUsersData().. I checked it in the auto generated class but it wasn't there but when I tried the query you gave it was actually there.
I also created the data class as you did and it worked! Thank you so much.
But could you please explain why the previous approach didn't work? Should I make every custom object as a separate data class?

Comment: I think there is no general rule, you have several options you can combine for each use-case. You can choose - to use `Converter` and to save object as a String or - you can choose separate `Entity` and link them with `Room Relations`. You can custom query's result type but you should understand that in some edge-cases Room couldn't understand how to turn raw SQLite fields into desired custom object. Your use-case was exactly the one Room couldn't digest (described Transformation #2). But I wouldn't make some general conclusion based on this use-case.